# How can I create my own datatype in python so that I could overwrite arithmetic operators?

Tags: python, numpy, gps, latitude-longitude, user-defined-types

I am currently using Python/Numpy to deal with geographical/GPS data (loving it!), and I am facing the recurring task to calculate distances between geographical points defined by a coordinate pair `pn = [lon, lat]`.

I have a function that I use like this: `dist = geodistance(p1, p2)` which is analog to euclidean distance in linear algebra (vector subtraction/difference), but occurs in geodesical (spherical) space instead of rectangular euclidean space.

Programmatically, euclidean distance is given by

```
dist = ((p2[0] - p1[0])**2 + (p2[1] - p1[1])**2)**0.5
```

Mathematically, this is equivalent to the "idiomatic" (for lack of a better word) sentence

```
dist = p1 - p1   # the "norm" of the vector difference, subtraction.
```

Currently, I get my distance like this:

```
p1 = [-51.598354,-29.953363]
p2 = [-51.598701,-29.953045]
dist = geodistance(p1, p2)
print dist

>> 44.3904032407
```

I would like to do this:

```
print p2 - p1  # these points now are from some fancy datatype

>> 44.3904032407
```

And the final goal:

```
track = numpy.array([[-51.203018 -29.996149]
                     [-51.203018 -29.99625 ]
                     [-51.20266  -29.996229]
                     [-51.20229  -29.996309]
                     [-51.201519 -29.99416 ]], dtype=fancy)  # (**) or something like

print numpy.diff(track)

>> ndarray([[   0.        ]
            [   7.03531252]
            [  39.82663316]
            [  41.50958596]
            [ 172.49825765]])
```

A similar thing is: if you take two `datetime` objects and subtract them, the operation returns a `timedelta` object. I want to subtract two coordinates and get a geodesic distance as the result.

I wonder if a class would work, but dtype (a "subtype" of float32, for example) would help a lot upon array creation from lists (** which is how I read things from xml files).

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Look into operator overloading.

Comment: You could subclass ndarray to overload the minus operator, but I would think twice before you do something potentially confusing. Could also add a new method to it, like `.dist()` of course. The numpy documentation has some simple examples. For just adding a method you don't really need to do much, otherwise it can be a bit tricky.

Comment: A problem you will have with numpy.array(..., dtype=fancy) is that you will lose the speed of numpy, because it will be considering arrays of python objects instead of numbers. Maybe you want to instead have a Coord type that sometimes contains a pair of numbers and sometimes contains a pair of arrays..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can define your own types by creating a class and writing a `__add__` or `__sub__` method.

For example:

```
class P(object):
    def __init__(self, lon, lat):
        self.lon = lon
        self.lat = lat

    def __sub__(self, other):
        dist = ((other.lon - self.lon)**2 + (other.lat - self.lat)**2)**0.5
        return dist
```

Given that you're currently getting the coordinates of your points using the list indexing syntax, you could also implement those:

```
class P(object):
    def __init__(self, lon, lat):
        self.lon = lon
        self.lat = lat

    def __sub__(self, other):
        dist = ((other[0] - self[0])**2 + (other[1] - self[1])**2)**0.5
        return dist

    def __getitem__(self, key):
        if key == 0:
            return self.lon
        elif key == 1:
            return self.lat
        else:
            raise IndexError

    def __setitem__(self, key, value):
        if key == 0:
            self.lon = value
        elif key == 1:
            self.lat = value
        else:
            raise IndexError
```

(I realize that the above may not be the most elegant way to do it).

That way, your new class is a drop-in replacement for the lists you're currently using.

The [Python documentation](http://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html) contains more information about the double-underscore methods you need to write in order to create your user-defined types. (The information you're looking for starts about half-way down the page)

Comment: As I currently understand it, I could not directly create arrays from lists using `dtype` keyword like `numpy.array(coordlist, dtype=fancy)`, but instead would have to create a list of instances of a, say, Coord class, then do `numpy.array(CoordList, dtype=object)`, isn't it? If possible, I'd like to have an actual numeric type, not a subclass of `object`, but if that's not possible I think that would be the way to go. Currently I am curious about the `numeric.Real` Abstract Base Class...

Answer (score 3):

Python Language Reference, §3.4.8, ["Emulating numeric types"](http://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html#emulating-numeric-types)

Specifically, `__sub__()`.

Comment: I have read about it, and also about Abstract Base Classes (`number.Real`, for example) but couldn't find a working example. What should I look for?

Comment: You wouldn't look for anything. `a - b` is `a.__sub__(b)` (unless it isn't, but that's another story).

Comment: I meant looking for how to create my new type, using for example the `numeric.Real` Abstract Base Class. Could I create my arrays using `numpy.array(coordlist, dtype=coordtype)` or I would have to subclass object and do it like `numpy.array(coordlist, dtype=object)`, then being `coordlist` a list of Coord(object) instances?

Comment: `coordtype` isn't a valid value for `dtype`. Also, since your type isn't *actually* a number (it is numeric, yes, but it doesn't meet the rest of the requirements for a number) it shouldn't be derived from another number type.